# How to calculate the intersection of 2 sectors in this object oriented example

Tags: python, class, object

I have solved pretty much everyhting in this exercise but the def intersect section, where it is asking to generate a new sector with the intersection.
They way I am doing it is generating a tuple so when I run this check I get an error AssertionError   because it is a tuple and not a string as expected in the check

I would appreciate some help in solving this part.

```
s2.fr = 60
s2.to = 100
s2.rad = 30
s3 = s1.intersect(s2)
assert str(s3)=="60 70 30"
```

```
from __future__ import annotations    #keep this in because of recursive annotations

class Sector: 
     fr: int
     to: int
     rad: int
    
     def __init__(self):
          '''Creates a circular sector with from and to angles 0 and radius 0.'''
          self.fr=0 
          self.to=0
          self.rad=0                      

     def rotate(self, angle: int)-> None:
          '''Rotates sector by the angle. For simplicity, assume that the rotation will result in a sector with fr <= to'''
          self.fr=self.fr+angle
          self.to=self.to+angle
          self.rad=self.rad    
    
     def intersect(self, other: Sector)-> Sector:
          '''Returns a new sector that is the result of the intersection of this sector with the other one. For simplicity, assume that the two sectors have non-empty intersection (overlap).'''
          return other.fr,self.to,other.rad
    
     def is_empty(self)-> bool:
          '''Returns True if the sector has empty area, otherwise returns False.'''
          if self.fr+self.to !=0:
            return False
          else:
            return True
    
     def __eq__(self, other: Sector)-> bool:
          '''Returns True this sector is the same as the other, otherwise False.'''
          return self.fr == other.fr
    
     def __str__(self)-> str:
          '''Returns string "F T R" where F is from angle, T is to, and R is radius.'''
           
          my_string =f"{self.fr} {self.to} {self.rad}"
          return my_string
```

Comment: Not sure why you are surprised your assertion fails when it’s comparing a tuple with a string; that will always fail. Have you tried converting the return from intersect into astring and then comaring? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

As far as I can tell, there is a flaw in your `intersect` method. You probably believe this method returns a new sector object (and your comment says so), but you are actually returning a tuple.
As s3 is a tuple, calling `str(s3)` is therefore pointless, and definitely not calling `__str__` method of your class (as you probably intend).

I would recommend you modify `intersect` to return a genuine `Sector`. Having optionally optional :-) arguments to your `__init__` would help in writing elegant and readable colde.

As a side note, in my opinion, comparing Objects based on their string representation is questionable. As you seem to be familiar with `__eq__`, why not use this to "natively" check equality ?